# Как значение функции вернуть в html?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно задать объекту рандомный цвет. Рандомный цвет делает функция, но вопрос в том, как значение этой функции установить в CSS?

Comment: Вы хотите стиль в файле CSS менять или просто у одного элемента?

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае "ваш объект".style.color = "ваш цвет";

Список других параметров стилей у объектов DOM можно посмотреть здесь https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('#myObj').style.background = `rgba(${myRnd(255)},${myRnd(255)},${myRnd(255)},1)`;
```